# backbone delegateevents delay all events - wrap it timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone and I was wondering if there is a way to globally delay any function call fired from a view? possibly by wrapping it in a timeout?

```
// this is the delegate events function:
delegateEvents: function(events) {
    if (!(events || (events = _.result(this, 'events')))) return this;
    this.undelegateEvents();
    for (var key in events) {
        var method = events[key];
        if (!_.isFunction(method)) method = this[events[key]];
        if (!method) throw new Error('Method "' + events[key] + '" does not exist');
        var match = key.match(delegateEventSplitter);
        var eventName = match[1], selector = match[2];

        // wrap method in a timeout
        var binding = function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log('fired in timeout');
                method();
            }, 1000);
        };

        binding = _.bind(binding, this);
        eventName += '.delegateEvents' + this.cid;


        if (selector === '') {
            this.$el.on(eventName, binding);
        } else {
            this.$el.on(eventName, selector, binding);
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

The issue here is that the event still fires normally rather that with a timeout. How can I wrap all events in a timeout? (I only really care about delegate-able events anyways, like 'click')

Comment: Have you ever tried to use _.debounce? If you wanted a callback to trigger after 500ms, you could just assign method = _.debounce(method, 500), then you would get a version of method that fires after 500ms.

Comment: I have not tried that. So if just replace _.bind with denounce and that's all?

Comment: Well, if it's method() that you want to delay, you could do the following: method = _.debounce(method, "delay"). I still don't understand why you do _.bind(binding,this) because you don't reference this in binding.